# Ajax success to redirect to another page and populate the fields of that page

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

How can I redirect to another page on ajax success and populate the fields of that page based on the json result of my webapi?

I have this ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
   url: '@Url.Action("GetRoster", "Home")',
   type: 'GET',
   data: {
     id: data.Id
   },
   dataType: "json",
   success: function(respo) {
     //redirect to another page and fill out the fields
   },
   error: function() {
     alert("Error");
   }
 });
```

On my controller, I have this:

```
  using(var client = new HttpClient()) {
  client.BaseAddress = new Uri(address);
  var response = client.GetAsync("Roster/?id=" + id);
  await response;

  var result = response.Result;
  if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
   var readContent = result.Content.ReadAsAsync < UserInfo > ();
   readContent.Wait();
   var user = readContent.Result;
   return Json(user, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
```

variable user contains the user information and what I want in my ajax success is to redirect it to my edit page and populate the fields based on the user information.

Comment: The whole point of ajax is to stay in the **SAME** page. If you want to redirect, do not use ajax! Make a normal submit and use `return RedirectToAction();` in the POST method.

Comment: Okay, so I'm incorrectly using ajax, thanks for the advice btw. But is there any other way to accomplish my goal?

Comment: As I noted in the first comment :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, my problem now is, the post action is in the button in the Datatables :( .Is it possible to make a normal submit on that scenario?

Comment: Sure. But I cannot guess what your code is :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
window.location.replace("abc");
```

or

```
window.location.href = url;
```

to redirect to other place. But the point of using AJAX is to stay in the same page!